# How to get set value for dropdownlist? In the method below I am setting the value for textbox and dropdownlist

Tags: vb.net

How to get set value for dropdownlist? In the method below I am setting the value for `textbox` and `dropdownlist`. textbox value is being set correctly but dropdownlist is not.
I am not sure if I forget something.

**aspx.vb** :

```
    Protected Sub mybotton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs)
        Dim btndetails As ImageButton = TryCast(sender, ImageButton)
        Dim gvrow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(btndetails.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

        textbox.Text = gvrow.Cells(4).Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "")
        dropdownlist.Text = gvrow.Cells(7).Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "")
    End Sub
```

Comment: You mean to add an item, currently non-existent, to your dropdwonlist?? Or select an item that is already on the items of the ddl??

Comment: I presume that the `textbox` is supposed to have cell 7 and the list is supposed to have cell 4? If you're getting any errors, what are they and if not, what is `dropdownlist` actuallly being set to? Also what kind of object is `dropdownlist`

Comment: no no errors. cell 7 is correct. i left couple lines out

Comment: select an item that is already on the items of the ddl

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value already exists in the dropdownlist you can use:
dropdownlist.SelectedText = gvrow.Cells(7).Text.Replace(" ", "")